# How to see a Google+ user's circles with google-api-python-client

Tags: python, google-plus, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to access a user's circles in this way:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
service = build('plus','v1',developerKey=my_developer_key) # <-- NOT the user's token
people_request = service.people().list(userId=my_gplus_id, collection='connected')
all_people = people_request.execute()
```

The user approved the following scope:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/107512995392892664693/people/connected?alt=json&key=... returned "Forbidden">
```

Any ideas? Thanks~!

**EDIT**: I tried the same with google's JS API. It doesn't use the "key" url param but instead uses a "bearer" header with the user's access token, perhaps I'm using the wrong token?

Answer (score 1):

The only supported `userId` is `me` for the currently authenticated user.